# Load a TransformerBlock & TokenAndPositionEmbedding keras model after saving it

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, transformer-model

Good morning,
I hope you are well and will help me get out of this situation. Basically, I trained a tensorflow.keras model by having defined a TransformerBlock class as well as a TokenAndPositionEmbedding class as you will see in my code. The problem I have is that when I reload the model I get the following error:

```
chat = tf.keras.models.load_model("FAQ_model_2.keras")
```

Error i got :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-a21ba74f84b1> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 chat = tf.keras.models.load_model("FAQ_model_2.keras")

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/base_layer.py in load_own_variables(self, store)
   3529         all_vars = self._trainable_weights + self._non_trainable_weights
   3530         if len(store.keys()) != len(all_vars):
-> 3531             raise ValueError(
   3532                 f"Layer '{self.name}' expected {len(all_vars)} variables, "
   3533                 "but received "

ValueError: Layer 'dense_13' expected 2 variables, but received 0 variables during loading. Expected: ['dense_13/kernel:0', 'dense_13/bias:0']
```

And there is the code i used to register my custom layers :

```
keras.saving.get_custom_objects().clear()

@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable()
class TransformerBlock(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, embed_dim, num_heads, ff_dim, rate=.1, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)

    self.embed_dim = embed_dim
    self.num_heads = num_heads
    self.ff_dim = ff_dim
    self.rate = rate

    self.att = tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=embed_dim)
    self.ffn = tf.keras.Sequential(
        [tf.keras.layers.Dense(ff_dim, activation="relu"), tf.keras.layers.Dense(embed_dim),]
    )
    self.layernorm1 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
    self.layernorm2 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
    self.dropout1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate)
    self.dropout2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate)

  def call(self, inputs, training):
    attn_output = self.att(inputs, inputs)
    attn_output = self.dropout1(attn_output, training=training)
    out1 = self.layernorm1(inputs + attn_output)
    ffn_output = self.ffn(out1)
    ffn_output = self.dropout2(ffn_output, training=training)
    return self.layernorm2(out1 + ffn_output)
  
  def get_config(self):
    config = super().get_config()
    # save constructor args
    config['embed_dim'] = self.embed_dim
    config['num_heads'] = self.num_heads
    config['ff_dim'] = self.ff_dim
    config["rate"] = self.rate
    return config



@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable()
class TokenAndPositionEmbedding(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, maxlen, vocab_size, embed_dim, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)

    self.maxlen = maxlen
    self.vocab_size = vocab_size
    self.embed_dim = embed_dim

    self.token_emb = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=embed_dim)
    self.pos_emb = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=maxlen, output_dim=embed_dim)

  def call(self, x):
    maxlen = tf.shape(x)[-1]
    positions = tf.range(start=0, limit=maxlen, delta=1)
    positions = self.pos_emb(positions)
    x = self.token_emb(x)
    return x + positions
  
  def get_config(self):
    config = super().get_config()
    # save constructor args
    config['maxlen'] = self.maxlen
    config['vocab_size'] = self.vocab_size
    config['embed_dim'] = self.embed_dim
    return config


# question
questionX = Input(shape=(29,), name="userQuestion")
questionInput = TokenAndPositionEmbedding(29, vocabLen+1, 32)(questionX)
#questionInput = LayerNormalization()(questionInput)
questionInput = TransformerBlock(32, 2, 32)(questionInput)
#questionInput = TransformerBlock(32, 2, 32)(questionInput)
questionInput = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(questionInput)


# class prediction
#classe = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.2)(questionInput)
classe = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation="relu")(questionInput)
classe = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.1)(classe)
classe = tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(classes), activation="softmax", name="next")(classe)



# model

chat = Model(inputs=[questionX], outputs=[classe], name="chat")
chat.summary()
chat.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(), optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(), metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Once the model has been trained i tested, i saved it by using :

```
chat.save("FAQ_model_2.keras")
```

And when i reload, i got the error message i provided.

Can you please help me ?

Thanks in advance.

I expect the saved model with TransformerBlock and TokenAndPositionEmbedding to load properly.